# Does Thor know that Thursday is named after him?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel

Thor has been a pretty frequent visitor to Earth (Midgard), and he has most likely been here on one or more Thursdays.

Has Thor said anything about this day being named after him?

Any continuity - comics or movie.

Comment: I can see why someone might downvote this.   (Not me.)   Personally, I would downvote "Does he know it's named after him", but I don't have a problem with "Has he commented on it?"   The second question is tangibly answerable.   The first one might be a little too fuzzy.   But presumably, if he knows that he is the Thor of early Norse mythology, then he would also realize the day is named after him.    So a question along those lines would also be okay in my book.

Comment: OK, edited :) Yeah obviously if he said something then he knows about it.  If he doesn't say something, he may or may not know about it - he just hasn't said anything.

Comment: Does he know/has he ever mentioned the fact that Tuesday, Wednesday and Friday are named after his [brother](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Tyr), [father](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Odin) and [mother](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Frigga)?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I'd happily upvote "is there any concrete evidence that shows that he knows?" even if that evidence was tangential.

Comment: And does Two-Face know that Tuesday is named after him?

Comment: I dk. Why don't you ask him.

Answer (score 48):

## He probably knows

- There's a scene in the 2011 film *Thor* in which the characters come across a book about Thor, the Bifrost, and so on. The page about Thor has the following words in large, bold letters:

  > THURSDAY - THOR'S DAY

  The characters share their findings and research with each other several occasions throughout the film, so it's possible that either Thor had a chance to look at this book or someone mentioned the information to him.

  [image]
- Thor and his friends seem to have a decent understanding of how their previous visits to Earth have impacted humanity.

  > FANDRAL: This isn't like a journey to Earth, where you summon a little lightning and thunder and the mortals worship you as a god.
  >   <sup><sub>- [*Thor* (2011)](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html)</sub></sup>

  Thor is aware that his previous visits to Earth have impacted history and civilization. Given that he knows some humans worshiped him as a deity, it seems very likely that he would also be aware that Thursday was named after him.

Comment: I'm not sure the library book is terribly convincing. Thor doesn't strike me as the 'book learnin' sort.

Comment: Theres not much in the way of proof in your answer :)

Comment: @JK the answer does not claim proof, only probability. There is no in universe answer here.

Comment: @JK. I don't think you're going to get any better than a screenshot of a book in-universe with the information written clear to see. Aside from a specific conversation about it, which there isn't.

Comment: @Gusdor:   I think this is a perfectly well evidenced answer.   It shows that Thor visited Earth and interacted with the locals at the time, and presumably he communicated with them.   So presumably he can understand Old Norse and also knows that the original term [literally meant *Thor's Day*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=thursday).   So unless he's just totally oblivious to etymology, he should know.

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph, after the first block quote, is a bit mangled. I'm pretty sure I know what you're trying to say, but you might want to clean that up.